# setting timeout on a SSIS 2005 script task

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I am using a script task in ssis 2005 which takes some time and getting a problems timing out with "The operation has timed out". Where abouts is the setting to change the timeout period? I cant seem to find it in the properties in task and I do not wish to make a global change to timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the problems with timeout is in the databases. You should define a new timeout in the connection managers you have in your SSIS package